# Redirecting using regular expression in .htacces

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have to redirect urls like
`www.site.com/?page=user?id=5`
to something like
`www.site.com/users/5`

I wrote this regular expression
`.*\?page=(.*)&id=(.*)`
But it doesn't seem to work?

Full redirect rule:

```
Redirect 302 ^/.*index.php\?page=(.*)&id=(.*) /$1/$2
```

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` directive works on URL path only ie  `/index.php` the part after `?` is part of  `QUERY_STRING` and it can not be matched using Redirect,  You need to use `mod-rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2? [L,R]
```